# how to use capabilities for Android device

Tags: c#, android, selenium, appium

I used to send capabilities to Android device (in C#) the following way, but now it's been deprecated.

```js
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.SetCapability("device", "Android");
capabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", "Galaxy Note5");
capabilities.SetCapability("newCommandTimeout", "6000");
capabilities.SetCapability("platformName", "Android");
capabilities.SetCapability("platformVersion", "6.0.1");
capabilities.SetCapability("unicodeKeyboard", true);
capabilities.SetCapability("noReset", true);
 capabilities.SetCapability("appPackage", "gov.telaviv.digitel.coast");
capabilities.SetCapability("appActivity", "gov.telaviv.digitel.coast.MainActivity");
_webdriver = new AndroidDriver<AppiumWebElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
```

What should I do now? how would I send capabilities dynamically?
I didn't find any documentation regarding it.

Comment: please go through this link : https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/#android-only here they have mentioned about capabilities for Android Device

Comment: @SurajJogdand it seems like a definition to me and not a way to implement. Am I wrong? if I'm not wrong please give me back my effort for searching :) .. I;m familiar with this documentation, I'm talking about a new way of implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your own **Element file** as per the **devices** , probably a **Json file** or **YAML file**

A example of YAML file is given below

```
Device:
  Htc620:
    Device_name: GDG59YE03161                                        #Device id
    server: http://localhost:4723/wd/hub                             #appium server URL
    appPackage:  com.android.dialer                                  #app package name of your application
    appActivity:  com.android.dialer.DialtactsActivity               #app activity of your application
    platfrom:  4.4                                                   #platfom version of your device
    automation:  Appium                                              #Appium is used in automationName instead of Uiautomator for deviced on android version 4.4
```

If you want the values to be filled dynamically in above **YAML file**, then you need to develop logic of doing it, you can use **adb** commands to get all the necessary values.

After having your **YAML\JSON** file ready, you can pass them as **--variable file** and use the values in script. Thats what we do in **python/RF**

Comment: 10x. I'll try it . not sure that I can send the `webdriver` an instance of caps that is a JSON